# cakephp multilingual website

Tags: cakephp, web, multilingual

We're planning for a `multi language` website, Any idea/tricks how can we achieve the same?

Are there some ready made `components/plug-ins` available in **CakePHP** like in open source technologies?

Kindly let me know.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP comes with its own i18n and l11n functions. They work well for my projects and if you don't have any other requirements they should be fine for you too. Have a look at the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1228/Internationalization-Localization#!/view/1229/Internationalizing-Your-Application) for more.